# server locking out username after 1 failed login attempt?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

I have the following C# method which is used for a custom authentication implementation:

```
    public bool Authenticate(AuthenticateRequest userCredentials)
    {
        var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
        var userName = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(userCredentials.NetworkUserId));
        var password = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(userCredentials.Password));
        var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, userCredentials.DomainName);
        var isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(userName, password);
        return isValid;
    }
```

This works well when the correct user credentials are provided. This also works well when incorrect user credentials are provided. The problem is that when invalid user credentials are provided only 1 time, the user account gets locked out and subsequent login attempts fail, even when the proper credentials are submitted.  Is there a way to configure this code or the server to allow 3 login attempts before the user account lockout happens?

Comment: well i'm guessing that in the database there is a flag to determine whether the user is locked or not? find the code where that flag is being set. 

In addition, what you can probably do is add another database field (if there's none already) to count the number of tries up to a maximum of 3 tries.

Comment: PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials() is an interface into an AD-specific authentication process.  It's not wired to a custom app DB

Comment: `AD-specific authentication process` You need to speak to the person who manages your AD-specific authentication process. Likely your network administrator.